# repeat checking of form data without submit (JavaScript, HTML, JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to submit a HTML form, only when all the fields do not return false in the Javascript code.

My HTML looks like this, for simplicity I have just kept the name and email

```
    <form method="post" action="RegistrationServlet" class="iform" 
           onsubmit="return sendForm();">

    <ul><li><label for="YourName">*Your Name <span id="regNameErr"></span></label>
    <input class="itext" type="text" name="YourName" id="YourName" /></li>

    <li><br /><label for="YourEmail">*Your Email <span id="regEmailErr"></span></label>  
    <input class="itext" type="text" name="YourEmail" id="YourEmail" /></li>

    <li><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="ibutton" name="SendaMessage"   
      id="SendaMessage" value="Send a Message!" readonly="readonly" /></li></ul></form>
```

The Javascript looks like this, again for simplicity I am just checking 2 fields:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" 
           src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.sendForm = function() {
             if (($("#YourName").val() == "") || ($("#YourName").val().length > 55)) {
                                    $("#YourName").addClass("required");
                                    window.scroll(0, 190);
                                    $("#regNameErr").text("required");
                                    return false;
                                }
                                if ($("#YourEmail").val() == "") {
                                    $("#YourEmail").addClass("required");
                                    window.scroll(0, 190);
                                    $("#regEmailErr").text("required");
                                    return false;
                                }

                                if (!isEmailValid($("#YourEmail").val())) {
                                    $("#YourEmail").addClass("required");
                                    window.scroll(0, 190);
                                    $("#regEmailErr").text("required");
                                    return false;
                                }  
                                $("#SendaMessage").val("Please Wait...");
                                return true;
                            }
```

Why is the sendForm() function not repeatedly being called to check that all fields are correct before submitting.  Any ideas?

Also I understand that I can add a bounty after 2 days but I am not seeing any button on the editor.

Can you help?

Comment: So you are saying once you submit it keeps trying to submit over and over again?

Comment: No If they submit a field and it is not correct then it should repeat till all fields a re correct and then submit.  Thanks

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for the sendForm() function to run repeatedly?  Also, the isEmailValid(...) function is missing from your source.  Was this intended?  I ask because if it is also missing from your code, the call to the function would fail and the form would be submitted.

Comment: Your question made it sound like it was running in an infinite loop. Do you want all of the errors to appear instead one at a time?

Comment: I have the email function but it is too long.  Thats why I'm redoing the form for a company because the email needs to check for a dash after the @ character so for example name@company-location.com.  I think Andrei got the right solution for me however

Answer (score 1):

`sendForm` is called only once per submit - this how it works, and there is no reason to call it multiple times.

If you want to have all your fields checked on submit - you should not `return` after each check. Instead you should postpone this action until the all fields are verified, and introduce some flag to remember results:

```
function() {
    var formValid = true;
    if (($("#YourName").val() == "") || ($("#YourName").val().length > 55)) {
        ...
        formValid = false;
    }
    if ($("#YourEmail").val() == "") {
        ...
        formValid = false;
    }

    if (!isEmailValid($("#YourEmail").val())) {
        ...
        formValid = false;
    }

    if (!formValid) {
        return false;
    }

    $("#SendaMessage").val("Please Wait...");
    return true;
}
```

Side note. Have you considered any jQuery validation plugins for this? Might save you some implementation and maintenance efforts.

Comment: Thats f@ brilliant. I will try it have you got a jquery example? pure awesome

Comment: @Alex, google gives plenty of options. Here is the [first](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)